# Using Haskell type classes to enforce commutativity

Tags: haskell, type-systems, typeclass

I want to define a type class for geometric objects that can be intersected together:

```
class Intersect a b c | a b -> c where
  intersect :: a -> b -> c
-- Language extensions: -XMultiParamTypeClasses, -XFunctionalDependencies
```

The idea is to have a general-purpose intersection functions that can handle objects of different types. One could imagine such instances as

```
instance Intersect Line Plane (Maybe Point) where
  ...
instance Intersect Plane Plane (Maybe Line) where
  ...
```

But I also want to declare that intersection is commutative:

```
instance (Intersect a b c) => Intersect b a c where
  intersect x y = intersect y x
-- Language extensions: -XUndecidableInstances
```

The problem is that whenever I evaluate `intersect x y` without first defining an instance of the form `Intersect a b c`, where `a` is the type of `x` and `b` is the type of `y`, **the program goes into an infinite loop**, presumably caused by recursive instance declaration about commutativity. Ideally I want something like `intersect Egg Bacon` to fail to type-check because no such instance was defined, not trap me in an infinite loop. How can I implement this?

Comment: Sounds like something you could try to do using type families. You might get a better response on stack overflow.

Comment: Here is a blog post about a monad that enforces commutativity, maybe it can help: http://gelisam.blogspot.ca/2013/07/the-commutative-monad.html

Answer (score 2):

First, you could use the [commutative](https://github.com/gelisam/commutative) package, in which case you would modify the type signature of `intersect` to the following, but otherwise the rest of your code would "just work":

```
instersect :: Commutative a b -> c
```

However, you can also use QuickCheck with hspec in order to run a property test on all instances of your typeclass to ensure that it does in fact commute. This may reduce overhead - you'd have to do a benchmark since I don't know off the top of my head. For instance:

```
import Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
    describe "intersect" $ do
        parallel $ it "should commute" $ do
            property $ \x y -> intersect x y == intersect (y :: Point) (x :: Line)
```